# function using fgets returns 0

Tags: c, fgets

I am writing a small calculator, intended for an arduino, using RPN (reverse polish notation). Because I also want to make the code run on my x86 laptop, with setting some configuration parameters for my calculator program, I use functions like `input_str`, `input_int` and `output_str`, so I can implement them differently for my laptop or the arduino.

Now in `input_str`

```
char *input_str(void) {
  #if IS_IO_STDIO
    char iobuf[IO_BUF_SIZE];
    fgets(iobuf, IO_BUF_SIZE, stdin);
    if (IS_DEBUG) { printf("1. iobuf: %s\n", iobuf); }
    if (IS_DEBUG) { printf("2. iobuf ptr: %p\n", iobuf); }
    return iobuf;
  #elif IS_IO_SERIAL
    // TODO: implement serial input str
  #endif // IS_IO_STDIO
}
```

using `fgets`, to get the user's input (for future calculations), `1. iobuf printout` properly prints out the string, typed in by the user, `2. iobuf ptr` properly prints out some `char *` unequal to 0.

When I use the return value of `input_str` in my ipo-loop:

```
int ipo_loop(int16_t *stack, int *sp) {
    // TODO: implement real ipo loop
    int is_exit = false;
    char *iobuf;
    while (!is_exit) {
        iobuf = input_str();
        if (IS_DEBUG) { printf("3. iobuf ptr: %p\n", iobuf); }
        output_str(iobuf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`3. iobuf ptr` suddenly shows, that `iobuf` is now pointing to 0.

Why is `iobuf` suddenly 0?

Is it some typecast issue from `char[IO_BUF_SIZE]` to `char *`?

Comment: You're returning an address to a local variable. Don't do that. Your compiler should've warned you.

Comment: Let me denote, that ```IS_DEBUG``` is defined 1, ```IS_IO_STDIO```  is defined 1, ```IS_IO_SERIAL``` is defined 0, and ```output_str``` is just using ```printf``` in stdio mode - the io-serial mode is not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks @DanielKamilKozar! So then the scope gets from ```input_str``` to ```ipo_loop``` the local variable is destroyed?

Comment: I'll rewrite ```input_str``` to the form ```void input_str(char *iobuf)```, writing the input to the pointer iobuf, instead of returning it.

Comment: That's much better, and you'll see this pattern used a lot around C code dealing with I/O. This also has the advantage of shifting the responsibility of managing memory to the caller : after all, your function is supposed to only read the data, while it doesn't necessarily need to care about how the memory was allocated. The caller might use a local variable, dynamically allocated memory, or even some other way to store the result of your function.

Comment: You can supply a buffer that is in scope for the calling function; or you can allocate dynamic memory in the called function, and return a pointer to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the below code

```
char *input_str(void) { 
  char iobuf[IO_BUF_SIZE];
  fgets(iobuf, IO_BUF_SIZE, stdin);
  /* some code */
  return iobuf; 
}
```

where you are returning local array `iobuf` is causes **undefined behavior**. The char array `iobuf` declared in `input_str()` has local scope and its scope ends when control exits from this function.

If you could have compile your code with [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) like `-Wall`, `-Wextra` etc, for e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic test.c
```

compiler could have warned you like

> warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable
>   'iobuf' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]

Above compiler warning tells everything about the issue & its readable.

Instead of returning local array, create the **dynamic array** & return it. For e.g

```
char *iobuf = malloc(IO_BUF_SIZE * sizeof(*iobuf));
/* @TODO if malloc was success i.e check return value of malloc */
```

After that scan the data using `fgets()` as you did below.

```
  fgets(iobuf, IO_BUF_SIZE, stdin);
```

And then retuen the dynamic array

```
  return iobuf;
```

In calling API `ipo_loop()` once you are done with dynamically returned array, don't forget to `free` it to avoid memory leakage. for e.g

```
iobuf = input_str();
/* processing with iobuf.. here iobuf is dynamically returned array */
free(iobuf);
```

Comment: You might also tell the OP to compile with warnings enabled for the compiler to help catch this and other mistakes: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: Thanks Achal. That works too! I now used a static array in the ```ipo_loop``` scope and give it to ```input_str``` as a function argument, so that ```input_str``` can write there, to prevent using malloc and free. I don't know which version is faster (but speed is not so important here).